# cannot resolve symbol 'driveService'

Tags: android, download, google-drive-api, storage, drive

I want download a file from google drive , I used this code (from google developers)

but i have an error  say "cannot resolve symbol 'driveservice'"

```
    String fileId = "0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M";
    OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    driveService.files().get(fileId)
            .set("acknowledgeAbuse", true)
            .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

build.gradle :

```
....
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'

compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev110-1.23.0'
```

}

Comment: Where is `driveService` declared? Where did you get this code from?